# difference between います and でいます and です?

Tags: grammar

When I Google translate the following three sentences, it gives me the same answer. Can someone explain me the differences and when to use them?

1. 僕は彼の兄です
2. 僕は彼の兄います
3. 僕は彼の兄でいます

It is all translated as "I am his brother".

Comment: Google translation is useful for getting an idea of what something about. But it is *completely* useless for learning Japanese. Try it on the following strings:

Answer (score 2):

## 僕は 彼の 兄です

It's safe to translate this as "I am his brother".

### Question: Who are you?

Answer: 僕は 彼の 兄です = I am his brother

### Question: How are you two related?

Answer: 僕は 彼の 兄です = I am his brother

---

## 僕は 彼の 兄 います

This is broken. It sounds like you're trying to say "I am his brother", but it's not a proper sentence.

"います" has several meanings - I recommend you research the word and go over some examples. One way of using います would be to explain that you **have** someone:

### Question: Do you **have** a brother?

Answer: 僕には 兄が います (I **have** a brother)

### Question: Do you **have** a boyfriend?

Answer: 僕には 彼氏が います (I **have** a BF)

The following are valid as a sentence:

- 彼には 兄が います。それは 私です (He has a brother - that's me)
- 彼には 私という 兄が います (He has a brother which is me)

---

## 僕は 彼の 兄で います

This is valid, but has a different message compared to the other examples. It sounds like you're saying "I **will continue to be** his brother".

### Question: Could you **continue to be** his big bro until he finds a parent?

Answer: 彼が 大きくなるまで 僕は 彼の 兄で います (Until he grows up, I will **continue being** his brother)

### Question: Will you **remain** a Japanese citizen or switch to Canadian?

Answer: 私は 日本人で います (I will **stay** Japanese)